# Was granting myself this permission a security risk?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

In a PowerShell script in Windows 10 Pro 64, I'm getting [access-denied errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558585/powershell-try-catch-loses-repeated-access-errors) on several folders, such as:

- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\Content.IE5
- C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup

I went to look at those folders in *File Explorer*. I never did get into them, but along the way, on three folders:

- C:\Windows\System32\config
- C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile
- C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\WMI

I got a message saying that I didn’t have permission to access them, but inviting me to click to get permission permanently. I clicked that. I’m now able to access those three folders like any other. In order to test what "permanently" meant, I rebooted. I'm still able to access those folders.

Three questions:

- Is it a security risk (or a bad idea for any other reason) to have those folders accessible? If so, how do I revert that permission?
- On the "RtBackup" folder, I got the same offer to give me permanent access, but when I clicked for that, the permission was denied and I was told that to get it I should go to the "Security" tab. Presumably that means of the folder properties. I'm thinking it might be a bad idea to mess around with security settings for a system folder. Is that right? What are the risks from doing that?
- In researching this, I came across the DOS command [TakeOwn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown). I wonder if that might allow me to access all these elusive folders and maybe eliminate the [access-denied errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558585/powershell-try-catch-loses-repeated-access-errors) in my PowerShell script. Would it? And would doing that be dangerous? What are the risks from running `TakeOwn` on an inaccessible folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File permissions are really designed for a multi-user system. If that's the case -- multiple people use this machine, or it's part of a corporate environment -- then giving yourself write permissions inside C:\Windows\System32\ means that you (or malware you download that's running as you) can muck things up for other users.

If this is a single-user system then the distinction between you and Admin is a bit less meaningful. As usual, there's a perfect XKCD for this:

[XKCD comic "Authorization"](https://xkcd.com/1200/)

[image: XKCD comic "Authorization"]

It's also worth noting that by giving yourself (and therefore any malware running as you) write permission to C:\Windows\System32\, you increase the chance that malware can escalate itself to being Admin, at which point it's easier for it to hide from any anti-virus software you might be running because now the malware is equally powerful as the AV.

Comment: Thank you. I take this to answer all three questions with "Yes, that is dangerous," and you've explained the risk. Could you therefore edit the answer to add instructions (preferably with a link to documentation) on how to revert the permission that I now regret granting? (And thanks for the introduction to xkcd!)

Comment: @NewSites, unlike most online forum type communities it is preferable when you have a follow up question like that for a user to post a new question with that question rather than ask in a comment. Part of the purpose of SE is to provide a source of questions others may ask and be able to find their answer as well. This tends to work best when questions/answers stay limited to their original scope.

Comment: @NewSites This forum tends to prefer answers about general security concepts. A question looking for step-by-step instructions on doing something in a specific operating system would be a better fit on `superuser.com`.

Comment: @YLearn - The request for instructions was not a follow-up. It was part of the original question. I asked, if granting the permissions was a security risk, how to revert it. But in response to your comment, I went ahead and posted that part of the question separately, and it has now been migrated to *SuperUser*: https://superuser.com/questions/1496261/how-do-i-revert-these-permissions . I hope someone knows the answer because it's pretty lame that Windows offered to let me grant the permission without warning me of the risks.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth - I don't need step-by-step instructions. Just a link to a documentation page explaining how to undo what Windows did when I clicked the button to grant the permission, would be great. I hope it's explained somewhere and that either here or in answer to my other question on *SuperUser* (linked in comment to @YLearn), someone will share the information on where to find it.

Comment: @NewSites -- I answered your question on your other post.

Comment: "you increase the chance that malware can escalate itself to being Admin" -- this is a bit of a quibble for me but this isn't increasing the risk, it's guaranteeing it'll happen.  Being involved with PenTests/RedTeams, the first thing that's done is to analyze privilege escalation capabilities.  The minute I have figured out I have WRITE access to System32, at least local administrator is a foregone conclusion and given admin habits, probably the domain.  I can now create System running Scheduled Tasks, overwrite Service targets, change Run keys, etc. etc., ad nauseum.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth - Your answer is helpful and I want to accept it, but my question asked if what I did was a security risk, and "If so, how do I revert that permission?" It's of interest to know that I'm at risk, but now that I know it, it's important to fix that problem. Somebody has said that this forum isn't for step-by-step instructions, and that's fine. But could I please have a clue on where to find information on how to repair the damage?

Comment: @thepip3r - You say in your comment above that you answered my follow-up question at https://superuser.com/questions/1496261/how-do-i-revert-these-permissions/ . But there is no answer showing for that question. Did it get deleted for some reason? I got an e-mail saying that an answer was posted that starts with "If you're trying to restore permissions to Windows core OS files/directories, MS has a KB article...", so I'd really like to see that answer and a link to the KB article.

Comment: @NewSites I'm not enough of a Windows expert to know exactly _"inviting me to click to get permission permanently"_ means, or what Windows does under the hood when you click it. That is a question you should ask on a forum or kb that's more Windows-focused.